# Fiddle when tried on real script not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my working fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/axpbe377/7/

I applied the same concept on below script but **it's not coloring the matching span's text** as it did in the fiddle. When I checked if the values are passed to the `colorMe()`, they did log out this:

**LOgs**

```
user= 5684a03cd15fd
show_all_tutors.js:394 morning= Wed
show_all_tutors.js:395 afternoon= Wed
show_all_tutors.js:396 evening= Wed
show_all_tutors.js:393 user= 5684acabd818b
show_all_tutors.js:394 morning= Thrs
show_all_tutors.js:395 afternoon= Thrs
show_all_tutors.js:396 evening= Thrs
show_all_tutors.js:393 user= 5684aec47a4fd
show_all_tutors.js:394 morning= Wed
show_all_tutors.js:395 afternoon= Wed
show_all_tutors.js:396 evening= 
show_all_tutors.js:393 user= 5684afd9c5967
show_all_tutors.js:394 morning= Wed,Thrs
show_all_tutors.js:395 afternoon= 
show_all_tutors.js:396 evening=  
......................................
.......................................

$(function()
{
    var data;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/search/show_all_tutors.php", 
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {

        data.forEach(function(user){
    colorMe(user.morning, user.afternoon, user.evening, user.UUID);
        $("#contents").append("<div>"+user.UUID+"</div><div class='morning_"+user.UUID+"'>Morning: <span class='Mon'>M</span><span class='Tue'>T</span><span class='Wed'>W</span><span class='Thrs'>T</span><span class='Fri'>F</span><span class='Sat'>S</span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='afternoon_"+user.UUID+"'>Afternoon: <span class='Mon'>M</span><span class='Tue'>T</span><span class='Wed'>W</span><span class='Thrs'>T</span><span class='Fri'>F</span><span class='Sat'>S</span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='evening_"+user.UUID+"'>Evening: <span class='Mon'>M</span><span class='Tue'>T</span><span class='Wed'>W</span><span class='Thrs'>T</span><span class='Fri'>F</span><span class='Sat'>S</span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div>");


    });//end forEach
    }

  });


});
```

This is the `colorMe()` function.

```
function colorMe(param, param2, param3, user_id){
    console.log("user= "+user_id);
    console.log("morning= "+param);
    console.log("afternoon= "+param2);
    console.log("evening= "+param3);
    var mornings = param.split(',');
    var afternoons = param2.split(',');
    var evenings = param3.split(',');

    $("div.morning_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
        return mornings.indexOf(this.className) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');

    $("div.afternoon_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
        return afternoons.indexOf(this.className) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');

    $("div.evening_"+ user_id +" span").filter(function(){
      return evenings.indexOf(this.className) > -1;
    }).css('color', '#26F525');
}
```

The json format data in `/search/show_all_tutors.php` is as follows:

```
[{"UUID":"5678f6c0b54da","morning":"","afternoon":"Thrs,Fri,Sat,Sun","evening":"Thrs,Fri,Sat,Sun"},{"UUID":"5678f6ef9fee1","morning":"Wed,Thrs","afternoon":"Wed,Thrs","evening":""}]
```

Comment: I don't think the fiddle worked for me. All the text is still black?

Comment: @Joshua, sorry this is the updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/axpbe377/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(function(){
    var data;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/search/show_all_tutors.php", 
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {

        data.forEach(function(user){

           $("#contents").append("<div>"+user.UUID+"</div><div class='morning_"+user.UUID+"'>Morning: <span class='Mon'>M</span><span class='Tue'>T</span><span class='Wed'>W</span><span class='Thrs'>T</span><span class='Fri'>F</span><span class='Sat'>S</span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='afternoon_"+user.UUID+"'>Afternoon: <span class='Mon'>M</span><span class='Tue'>T</span><span class='Wed'>W</span><span class='Thrs'>T</span><span class='Fri'>F</span><span class='Sat'>S</span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='evening_"+user.UUID+"'>Evening: <span class='Mon'>M</span><span class='Tue'>T</span><span class='Wed'>W</span><span class='Thrs'>T</span><span class='Fri'>F</span><span class='Sat'>S</span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div>");  

           colorMe(user.morning, user.afternoon, user.evening, user.UUID);
        });//end forEach
});
```